# php json_encode fails without error

Tags: php, json

```
PHP Version: 5.6.15RC1
Compiler: MSVC11 (Visual C++ 2012)
Architecture:x86
```

I am having problem **json_encode** ing a multi dimensional php array.
The main problem is that no error is generated (json_last_error=0).

The array is indexed by a string and testing each of these indexes seperately has been done within the array compilation has been done on the outer indexes by  using:

```
$test = json_encode($account[$q_id]);
if (strlen($test) < 2) {
    $error = json_last_error();
}
```

Stepping through several showed correct json output. Then a breakpoint in the if statement was placed to identify any encoding issues, however it never stopped on the $error... line.

Database connection:

```
$connection_cfg = array("Database" => $db["database"], "CharacterSet" =>     "UTF-8", "UID" => $db["uname"], "PWD" => $db["pword"], "ReturnDatesAsStrings" =>true);
$this->connection = sqlsrv_connect($db["host"], $connection_cfg);
```

I am stuck on how to proceed to debug this.

Comment: I don't understand. If it produced correct JSON output, why should it go to the `$error` line? What's the value of `account[$q_id]`?

Comment: I don't see how the database connection is relevant to this. Once the data has been fetched into a PHP array, it doesn't matter where it came from.

Comment: an empty json string is `[]` which is 2 characters. try replacing `strlen($test) < 2` with `strlen($test) == 2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An empty JSON string looks like this:

```
[]
```

That is 2 characters.
Your error-detection will not work because it checks for 1 or less characters.

Change

```
if (strlen($test) < 2) {
    $error = json_last_error();
}
```

To

```
if (strlen($test) == 2) {
    $error = json_last_error();
}
```

And your error-detection should work.

If you are unable to resolve the problem that is indicated in the JSON error, please update us with the error.

Answer (score -1):

Lesson learnt, there should always be some distrust in debugging tools (netbeans watches etc).
I created the error check when seeing a random '{' as the output (don't know why netbeans displayed it like this).
It was the javascript that was broken in a line such as

```
var a=<?php echo $thejsonstuff ?>
```

and I attempted the php debug from netbeans results first.